# titan exception occurs at commit time

Tags: titan

i'm trying bulk-load to titan database. storage backend is Cassandra, and index backend is elastic search.

I'm getting an exception at commit time.
exception message is 'Could not commit transaction due to exception during persistence' and stack trace is like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph$3.apply(StandardTitanGraph.java:621)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph$3.apply(StandardTitanGraph.java:618)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:652)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.isEmpty(Iterables.java:1001)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.commit(StandardTitanGraph.java:667)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.commit(StandardTitanTx.java:1352)
    at com.ncrm.LoaderImpl.loadData(LoaderImpl.java:338)
    at com.ncrm.TripleLoader.execute(TripleLoader.java:52)
    at com.ncrm.TripleLoader.main(TripleLoader.java:24)
```

when i trace to titan source, exception occurs in this line:

```
//3.2 Commit schema elements and their associated relations in a separate transaction if backend does not support
        //    transactional isolation
        boolean hasSchemaElements = !Iterables.isEmpty(Iterables.filter(deletedRelations,SCHEMA_FILTER))
                || !Iterables.isEmpty(Iterables.filter(addedRelations,SCHEMA_FILTER));
```

this exception occurs only in multi-threaded loading. there's no problem in single threaded loading. 
Please help me ~~

Comment: Is there any more to that exception? are you experiencing some kind of locking exception?

Comment: I don't think it's a locking exception. maybe exception occurs when titan carries out some integrity check before commit. I'm guessing some schema information goes invalid in a multi-threaded loading environment

Comment: Perhaps you need to update your question with more snippets of the relevant code that produce the problem.  offhand i'm not sure what's wrong.